# one button two actions

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i want to submit data from one button in the databse and the same button should export
the CSV of the databse, i tried but it doesn't work only dat is being sent 
i have two buttons

```
<div class="mws-form-item large">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit1" value="Generate Serials" />
<a href="get_csv.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<input type="button" name="get_csv" value="Export CSV"/></a>
</div>

and tried the in the following way
<div class="mws-form-item large">
<a href="get_csv.php" style="text-decoration:none">
<input type="submit" class="button" name="submit1" value="Generate Serials" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What a ridiculous idea. just have two buttons - one for export the other for submit.

Comment: Yes, even though possible.. its a bad idea. I'm pretty sure no user would be expecting that :) so why surprise them? :)

Comment: This will cause bad UX. This is what conventions are for.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, then you can bind click event to the submit button and perform all the operations you need in the function being called after click.

For eg :

```
<input type="submit" id="submitBut">
```

For this you can have :

```
$("#submitBut").click(function(){

//operations you need to perform

})
```